# Nesting UITabBar into UINavigation Controller

Tags: uitabbarcontroller

Hiya, I would like to know if there's an example of this anywhere. Basically I would like to push the UITabBar, and keeping with apple's guidelines I can only do this by placing the UITabBar(not the controller) in a viewController. Examples of this are in the Music selection on your iPhone/iTouch when you hit the "Now Playing" nav item, notice the tab bar pushes over.

This is somewhat of the flow I'm trying to accomplish

```
                                                 -----> Table (cell 1)----> Detail View 
                                                 |
Navigation Controller ----> UITabBar-|----------> view 2
                                                 |
                                                  -----> view 3
```

So when the app launches I'm greeted with my tab bar and when I select a cell from the tableView the detail view is pushed onto the stack resulting in a possible customized button bar at the bottom of that view.

Another good example of this functionality is the [B]NYTimes [/B]app (it's free if you want to check it out)

Now I got the basics of this running, but I'm getting crashes when trying to wire IBOutlets to the tab items in IB. Would appreciate some insight on this.

Thx much!

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy. The viewcontroller you push on the stack (the one which should hide the tabbar) should have the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property set to YES.

```
viewcontrollerbeingpushed.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```